# Caching with entity framework 6 and get notified when something changed

Tags: entity-framework, caching

Lets say that querying certain scenarios takes some time. For example to get a certain entity I have to make a join of several tables. Is there a way to cache the result and when something changed in the entity that cache get destroyed?

I can do this manually but as you want to cache more this becomes tedious to maintain.

Is there a way to automate this with entity framework? My ultimate goal is query an entity and that goes to the cache then if it is not there it will get it from the database else it will return it from the cache, if something changed in that entity then it will be removed from the cache.

I want this to be implemented without me caring about checking the cache and let that library do this behind the scene, i.e. the whole scenario is abstracted to me by simply querying an entity.

Is there a library/technique that can implement this?

I am using EF6, Sql Server, ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 1):

This is called second level caching. I want to implement this too. As far as I know this is not supported by EF6. I have seached the internet a lot and find some solutions, but they are tedious to implement. The easy way is to use a solution like NCache (both commercial and free).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, so you are saying that from your search the only way is to implement this manually and use NCache to facilitate caching on different machines (distributed caching)?